# Tweepy not unretweeting Tweets from over a month ago

Tags: python, tweepy

I have the following code, which goes through my user timeline and cleans it up  by Unretweeting all the Retweets. The problem is that when I reach Tweets over a month ago, it doesn't Unretweet them, so how do I solve this?

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, tweet_mode = 'extended').items(3200):
    
    status = api.get_status(tweet.id)

    if status.retweeted == True or tweet.full_text.startswith('RT @'):
        api.unretweet(tweet.id)
        print('Tweet has been Unretweeted.\n')
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a Twitter limitation? Are you able to make the change manually via the web site?

Comment: It seems like I can make the change on the site, but the Tweet count seems to remain the same.

Comment: I changed the status to the original status of the Tweet rather than the Retweet, and it seems to Unretweet them, but it's not changing the Tweet count at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `api.unretweet(tweet.id)` to `api.destroy_status(status.id)`.